# logback GELF appender attached twice

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, configuration, logback

I'm trying to get Graylog / GELF setup.  Locally, my console appender only logs the message once, but on my graylog server, I see the same log message twice.  I turned on debugging and I see:

```
15:04:53,223 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
15:04:53,223 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
15:04:53,223 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
15:04:53,229 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [biz.paluch.logging.gelf.logback.GelfLogbackAppender]
15:04:53,233 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [GELF]
15:05:13,615 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [GELF] to Logger[ROOT]
15:05:13,615 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [biz.paluch.logging.gelf.logback.GelfLogbackAppender]
15:05:13,615 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [GELF]
15:05:13,617 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [GELF] to Logger[ROOT]
15:05:13,617 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to WARN
15:05:13,617 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@34341ee8 - Propagating WARN level on Logger[ROOT] onto the JUL framework
15:05:13,617 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
15:05:13,617 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
```

I noticed "Attaching appender named [GELF] to Logger[ROOT]" appears twice, which I assume is why I'm getting double logging only on Graylog.

Here's my config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">

    <springProperty scope="context" name="appName" source="spring.application.name"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="gelfHost" source="gelf.host"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="gelfPort" source="gelf.port"/>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] [%-5level] %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- This 'if' action is to avoid this appender from failing before spring cloud config is fetched with the external properites we are looking for -->
    <if condition='isDefined("gelfHost")'>
        <then>
            <springProfile name="graylog">
                <appender name="GELF" class="biz.paluch.logging.gelf.logback.GelfLogbackAppender">
                    <graylogHost>${gelfHost}</graylogHost>
                    <graylogPort>${gelfPort}</graylogPort>
                    <version>1.1</version>

                    <!--<facility>java-test</facility>-->
                    <extractStackTrace>true</extractStackTrace>
                    <filterStackTrace>true</filterStackTrace>
                    <mdcProfiling>true</mdcProfiling>
                    <timestampPattern>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSS</timestampPattern>
                    <maximumMessageSize>32768</maximumMessageSize>

                    <originHost>${HOST}</originHost>
                    <!-- This are static fields -->
                    <additionalFields>application=${appName},env=${DEPLOYED_ENV:-${ENV}}</additionalFields>
                    <!-- Optional: Specify field types -->
                    <additionalFieldTypes>application=String,env=String</additionalFieldTypes>

                    <mdcFields>user.id</mdcFields>
                    <includeFullMdc>true</includeFullMdc>

                    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
                        <level>${GRAYLOG_THRESHOLD:-INFO}</level>
                    </filter>
                </appender>

                <root>
                    <appender-ref ref="GELF" />
                </root>
            </springProfile>
        </then>
    </if>

    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

any ideas why my gelf appender appears to be created/attached twice?

PS: I'm using spring-boot and the my logback config file is named "logback-spring.xml" and it's in /src/main/resources.  I've also confirmed my config file is the only logback config on the classpath.

Comment: Does this only show up when you are using the Spring Cloud Config server? I'd be curious if it's something that happens with the bootstrap phase of startup.

Comment: @nerdwaller - I'll see if I can spin up a non-cloud enabled app and verify.  I'm seeing many posts about logback config w/ spring-cloud having issues, but they aren't the same issues I'm seeing.  My app isn't reporting that it started twice....

Comment: FWIW - I added my graylog server and port to my bootstrap.yml file and updated my logback-spring.xml to remove the "if host defined" check, my graylog appender only gets created and attached to the root logger once and I get the expected behavior